# Can i get STATIC c++ azure storage client library?

Tags: azure, static-libraries, azure-storage, nuget-package

Recently i've installed Azure Storage Client Library for C++ using NuGet in Visual Studio 2015 by running `Install-Package wastorage`. But it seems that only a dynamic version of this library was installed.

How can i get a static one?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, I assumed that you want to install the `wastorage` package with the specific version. If so, you could follow the command below:

`Install-Package wastorage -Version 2.5.0`

**Note:** You could leverage `Find-package wastorage -allversions` to list versions of your package or directly access the [wastorage package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/wastorage) in your browser, in order to find the available versions.

For more details, you could refer to the [command reference](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/powershell-reference#install-package).

Comment: I need the same version of this library but static one, not dynamic one. In other words, i want to link my project only against a .LIB file without .DLL file.

Comment: As I known, here is the source code of [Azure Storage Client Library for C++](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-cpp). For the best development experience, it's recommend that developers use the official Microsoft NuGet packages for libraries. Also you could send your feedback on this [forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).